# Trouble setting up subdomain in Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I just set up a micro instance of an Ubuntu web server an Amazon EC2. Everthing is running great, I've managed to configure the VirtualHost but I'm having a hard time setting up a subdomain. Here's what I've done:

```
$ mkdir /var/www/mydomain
$ mkdir /var/www/mysubdomain
$ chmod -R 774 /var/www/mydomain
$ chmod -R 774 /var/www/mysubdomain

$ vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomian

<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerAdmin me@me.com 
 ServerName mydomain.com 
 ServerAlias www.mydomain.com 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomian 
</VirtualHost> 

$ vim /etc/apache2/site-available/mysubdomain

<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerName mysubdomain.localhost # also tried mysubdomain.mydomain.com 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/mysubdomian

 <Directory /var/www/mysubdomain/ >
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost> 

$ ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomian /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomian
$ ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysubdomain /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysubdomain
```

After restarting Apache mydomain.com works fine but mysubdomain.mydomain.com doesn't work. Any ideas?

PS I've also added staging.localhost to /etc/hosts (not sure if I need to do that but...)

Comment: I am little confused here. Your DocumentRoot is at /var/www/mysubdomain, but your directory directive is at is at /var/www/staging. Do you mean Directory to be /var/www/mydomain?

Comment: @Rilindo yes you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, thanks for the help guys. It turns out my apache config files where fine. I needed to create an A (host) record at with my domain registar that pointed to the EC2 "Elastic" IP.

Answer (score 3):

remove any symlinks in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and then

```
sudo a2ensite mydomain
sudo a2ensite mysubdomain
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Also, make sure your NameVirtualHost directive comes before the VirtualHost configs are read. An easy way to do this is to add it to /etc/apache2/ports.conf

You probably have a default conf in sites-available (probably symlinked as 000-default in sites-enabled). If you want to keep that default config, you can add NameVirtualHost line at the beginning of that file.

Comment: I removed the 000-default from sites-enabled. Should I re-add it?

Comment: Also, do you think it's better to use myIpAddress:80 or *:80 for the NameVirtualHost value?

Comment: sites-enabled/000-default -> sites-available/default is used for requests that don't match a ServerName or ServerAlias directive. It's probably a good idea to have a config for that, so if in doubt, keep it.

Comment: Unless you have a reason to specify the IP address (like for hosting  sites on a different IPs) you might as well use *:80

Answer (score 1):

chances are your NameVirtualHost is wrong.. it should match what is in your virtualhost section so it should be

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Also not sure what this is

```
$ ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomian $ vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomian
```

I'm guessing a typo? but are they in sites-enabled ok?

Comment: A added NameVirtualHost and no change. I get this warning when i restart Apache: `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`

Comment: yes that is a typo

Comment: then they aren't in sites-enabled correctly